# WordPress: How can override the Dashboard CSS

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, dashboard

Hi I was wondering is there an easy way to override the WordPress Dashboard CSS styles?

Please help. Even a jQuery solution will do.

Comment: not sure if this is better placed on the [wordpress stack exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert This Into a Plugin or a Custom Theme functions.php

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'showhiddencustomfields' );

function showhiddencustomfields() {
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen,projection' type='text/css' href='your-custom-css-file.css'>";
}
```

Use a developer tool bar to figure out which css rule you need to add to your custom css file.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a pretty solid guide to altering it: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes

Is this what you had in mind?